# onOptionsItemSelected not called on the first tap

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I have a menu that I hide/show in the toolbar. When the overflow menu item is tapped, the rest of the icons are shown using the following code:

```
override fun onMenuOpened(featureId: Int, menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menu.forEach {
            if(it.actionView == null) {
                it.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
            }
        }
        return super.onMenuOpened(featureId, menu)
    }
```

However, after all the menu items are shown, I have to tap twice before the `onOptionsItemSelected` function is called. I have a suspicion that this is something to do with changing the menu items to `SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS` but I'm not quite sure how exactly, or if that's even the issue. What could be causing me having to tap twice on a menu item?

Comment: You can put `SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS` in the menu `XML` directly if you want.

Comment: Well the idea was I only want some menu items shown if the user taps on the overflow icon, otherwise they should stay hidden

Comment: Yeah I got it The items you want to be hidden just put `SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS` in the XML if you don't want to change it in the runtime.

Comment: Putting ```SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS``` in the xml will show the icons by default, as opposed to being hidden. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Sorry mate. `app:showAsAction="never"` do this.